# vscode with debugpy: Recursive mode like pdb missing?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

> I am trying to configure vscode debugger for recursive debugging with
> debugpy. In this regard:
>
> 1. I open a jupyter console and attach the vscode debugger to the kernel.
> 2. I am then able to call some function and let vscode stop at some breakpoint.
> 3. The ipython cell seems to be blocked now and won't let me input further commands.
> 4. Leaving the breakpoint brings the ipython cell back to life.
>
> This behaviour is confusing, since I would rather expect to be able to
> continue working with the console, that is evaluating statements,
> create plots, ... while stopping at the breakpoint. In addition I'd
> expect to debug further code recursively, i.e. to let vscode stop at
> some other breakpoint and return later on to the first breakpoint.
> With python pdb this is possible by executing the "debug 'code'"
> command, which creates a nested pdb instance.
>
> Is it possible to replicate the pdb behavaiour with vscode by
> configuration, ie.:
>
> - Go to the next cell when the breakpoint is hit an allow user input in ipython.
> - Provide some interactive magic commands to control the debugger from ipython (e.g. debug 'code')
>
> Thanks, Daniel

**Follows an example:**

Define some dummy module 'my_module.py':

```
def fun():
import pdb; pdb.set_trace() 
print('fun')
def rec_fun():
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace() 
    print('fun')
        
a = 1
import pdb; pdb.set_trace() 
b = 2
```

Then run a python console.

Then enter in your terminal:

```
import my_module  # This will stop at the breakpoint and allow user further user input in the console, e.g. `print(a)`
# press c to completely load the module    
my_module.fun() # This will stop the debugger at the breakpoint inside function fun
import my_module # this will load the module for the debugger instance
debug my_module.rec_fun() # this will launch a nested debugger instance 
# Press c+enter: The nested instance will stop at breakpoint inside rec_fun()
# Press c+enter: The debugger will move to the previous breakpoint
# Press c+enter: The debugger will leave and go back to normal REPL mode.
```

This workflow seems not to be possible with vscode/debugpy. The key point in my opinion is keeping the shell alive with pdb-debugger. Some [interactive commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) are a subsequent problem. Is it possible to configure pydebug accordingly? What do you think?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example that can minimize the reproduction of this problem and related screenshots?

Comment: @JillCheng: I modified my post and provided an example! Thanks!